# Unable to insert any record and returns error:MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   //mysql_connect('localhost','root','')or die(mysql_error());
   //mysql_select_db('ecommerce');
   include_once ('mysql_connect.php');
   if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
   {
      // $image=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
       if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$_FILES['image']['name']))
       {
          if(!empty($_POST['description']))
          {
              $d=$_POST['description'];
          }
          else
          {
             $d=NULL;
          }
          $query="INSERT INTO uploads(file_name,file_size,file_type,description)VALUES('{$_FILES['image']['name']}',{$_FILES['image']['size']},'{$_FILES['image']['type']}',$d)"
                or die(mysql_error());
          mysql_query($query);
       }
   }
}
```

**There's no error in database connection.The picture also successfully saved inside the folder but no data inserted in mysql. Kindly assist..Your  help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to put the `or die(mysql_error());` *after* the mysql_query call. Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: try this 
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: You may also need to put single quotes around your description variable since I assume that is a CHAR or VARCHAR database field.  Since $d can also be NULL, it might be better to use `$d="'"..$_POST['description'].."'";` in the `if` block and `$d="NULL";` in the `else` block;  I suspect your `$d` string is not getting inserted into `$query` quite like you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would help

```
$query="INSERT INTO uploads(file_name,file_size,file_type,description)VALUES('".$_FILES['image']['name']."',".$_FILES['image']['size'].",'".$_FILES['image']['type']."','".$d."')";
```

Comment: if you are using the ".$var_name." then no need to use curly brackets remove them.

Comment: I htink you are trying to insert your php variable names into your DB. Probably if you concatenate there values instead.

Comment: But still in this query the `$d` is'nt in `{}` and is not `".$var."`

Comment: @user this is still vulnerable to SQL injection, like every other answer here as well. Read up on http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Pekka is right you might want to trow inthere some `htmlspecialchars()` and some validation (maybe regex) and some other things! Good luck I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

```
$query="INSERT INTO uploads(file_name,file_size,file_type,description)VALUES('{$_FILES['image']['name']}',{$_FILES['image']['size']},'{$_FILES['image']['type']}','$d')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

I'm assuming your `description` field doesn't just take integers.  Put single quotes around strings being inserted into the database.

mysql_query is also deprecated.  Use mysqli or pdo to perform queries.

Answer (score -2):

```
$query="INSERT INTO uploads(file_name,file_size,file_type,description)VALUES('{$_FILES['image']['name']}',{$_FILES['image']['size']},'{$_FILES['image']['type']}', '$d')"
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
```